# Change pattern lock to Thin Pattern Lock like in ICS

Tags: pattern-lock

Device: Micromax A57
Android: 2.3

How can I change the size of the unlock pattern grid like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtJQP.jpg]

Comment: That is ROM dependent, do not think you can change the grid size as its built in. Solution would be to look for a alternative lock screen, am sure there is plenty on the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Go Locker" 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jiubang.goscreenlock

Gives you a wide variety of lock screens to choose from.